# How to serialize to a variable

Tags: c#, serialization

The following code sample shows how to serialize/deserialize to a file.  How could I modify this to serialize to a variable instead of to a file? (Assume the variable would be passed in to the read/write methods instead of a file name).

```
    public static void WriteObject(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Creating a Person object and serializing it.");
        Person p1 = new Person("Zighetti", "Barbara", 101);
        FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        DataContractSerializer ser =
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
        ser.WriteObject(writer, p1);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public static void ReadObject(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deserializing an instance of the object.");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,
        FileMode.Open);
        XmlDictionaryReader reader =
            XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));

        // Deserialize the data and read it from the instance.
        Person deserializedPerson =
            (Person)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
        reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}, ID: {2}",
        deserializedPerson.FirstName, deserializedPerson.LastName,
        deserializedPerson.ID));
    }
```

Comment: What type of variable would you want to be passing in? A string? a MemoryStream?

Comment: What kind of variable do you have in mind? `byte[]`?

Comment: `p1` is a variable and holds everything you want.

Comment: Actually, that's something else I was hoping to get a suggestion on.  In this scenario, I really just want to make a copy of my object.  I will be immediately deserializing it into a variable that is the copy.  I know I could implement ICloneable, but I need to use serialization anyway so I figured I could just reuse that code. (Obviously this is just an example I lifted from Microsoft and my actual code will be serializing any number of different types).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for stating the obvious ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `FileStream` to a memory stream and dump it to a `byte[]`.

```
public static byte[] WriteObject<T>(T thingToSave)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Serializing an instance of the object.");
    byte[] bytes;
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, thingToSave);
        bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    }
    return bytes;

}

public static T ReadObject<T>(byte[] data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deserializing an instance of the object.");

    T deserializedThing = default(T);

    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using(var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        // Deserialize the data and read it from the instance.
        deserializedThing = (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
    }
    return deserializedThing;
}
```

Comment: Do you suppose a MemoryStream would be better/worse?

Comment: Better or worse than using a byte[] buffer?

Comment: I would consider a `MemoryStream` a `byte[]` buffer that implements [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx)

Comment: Just one more question: (Why) is it necessary to set stream.Position = 0?  Would it not be defaulted to that?